# I need a browser chrome/firefox extension to list all iframe src in the current page. Any recommendation?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, plugins

I am looking for browser (chrome/firefox) extension to list all iframe src in the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty trivial to do in JavaScript:

```
 var allIframesOnPage = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
 var len = allIframesOnPage.length;
 window.console.log('There are ' + len + ' iframes on the page.');
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   var current = allIframesOnPage[i];
   window.console.log('iframe[' + i + '].src == "' + current.src + '"');
 }
```

Combine that with a bookmarklet generator such as [this one](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/), and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the script. However, I haven't developed any extension... Not sure how to make use of this script. I am looking for extension whose icon on the tool bar, clicking on it should list iframes sources where I should be able to go to specific iFrame link in new window.

Comment: Thanks for introducing bookmarklet. Since, there is no direct extension available, I could live with bookmarklet and little javascript.